# How to get context in showDialog with BlocBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, popup, bloc, showdialog

in a class, I have a BlocProvider, then I would like to show a Dialog in which I have a BlocBuilder. But I think, because of the function showDialog(), I have this error :

> BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a Bloc of

Answer (score 0):

Store `context` of `BlocBuilder` as field:

```
BuildContext _bloxContext;

...

BlocBuilder<BlocClass, BaseState>(
  builder: (mContext, state) {
    if (_bloxContext == null) _bloxContext = mContext;
  }
),
```

and use it everywhere you want:

```
BlocProvider.of<BlocClass>(mContext).add(Fetch());
```

I hope it's useful for you.

Comment: yes thanks, but in my case, in the MotherClass, I have a Multiprovider(... , child : DaughterClass) and in the Daughterclass, I call showDialog(.., child: BlocBuilder(..)) and  have the error ''BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a Bloc of __ ", it looks like the function breaks the context

Comment: If you can share your code so maybe I can help you better